# Xml based slide show error in as3, Error 1009 from sending null to an event listener?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm looking for some help with an xml based slide show.

As it is the code is a bit sloppy and it's not entirely completed, but atm I just can't get past the current error i'm receiving.

The error i'm getting is (translated) something like:
TypeError: Error #1009: It's not possible to to get access to a property or method with the object referens null.

I'm guessing this originates from the calls to the event listener swapSlide().
Would very much appreciate some help (and of course other hints on what i may be doing wrong, other than that the code looks horrible ofc ;) ).

My code in it's full so far:

package {

```
import caurina.transitions.Tweener;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;

/**
 * ...
 * @author PQ
 */
public class  XmlSlide extends MovieClip {

    //   object properties
    private var _currentContainer:Sprite;           //  current container, is in the front
    private var _currentActiveSlide:int = -1;       //  current active slide
    private var _slideCount:int;                    //  amount of slides
    private var _slideTimer:Timer;                  //  Timer calls the swap function at set time
    private var _slideContainer1:Sprite;
    private var _slideContainer2:Sprite;
    private var _slideLoader:Loader;                //  loades the slides
    private var _xmlPath:String = "xmlfile.xml";    //  xml URL
    private var _xmlLoader:URLLoader;               //  loads xml file
    private var _xmlData:XML;                       //  holds the XML data
    private var _slideDelay:uint;                   //  delay between slides
    private var _textDelay:uint;                    //  delay before text appears
    private var _imgWidth:uint;                 
    private var _imgHeight:uint;
    private var _randomize:uint;                    //  display slides randomly or not
    private var _useSwapSlide:uint;                 //  change slides or use 1 and the same
    private var _imgURL:String;                     //  imgurl + imgname
    private var _startLoc:String;                   //  top, right, bottom, left, (default (middle))
    private var _startXY:Array;                     //  holds the x and y for sliding imgs startpos
    private var _textTimer:Timer;
    private var _textWidth:uint;                    //  width of text field
    private var _textHeight:uint;                   //  height of text field
    private var _textContainer:TextField;
    private var _formatsText:TextFormat;
    private var _mainContainer:MovieClip;           //  the main movieclips that holds everything.

    //   object constructor
    public function XmlSlide() {

        //  stage inställningar
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        _mainContainer = new MovieClip;
        addChild(_mainContainer);
        _mainContainer.x = 0;
        _mainContainer.y = 0;

        var _textContainer = new TextField();
        var _formatsText = new TextFormat();

        //  startar xml laddning
        _xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
        _xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoadComplete)
        _xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(_xmlPath));      
    }


    private function onXmlLoadComplete(e:Event):void {

        _xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);

        //   set XML data
        _slideCount = _xmlData.*.length();
        _randomize = _xmlData.@randomize;
        _useSwapSlide = _xmlData.@swapimg;
        _slideDelay = _xmlData.@slidedelay;
        _textDelay = _xmlData.@textdelay;
        _imgWidth = _xmlData.@imgwidth;
        _imgHeight = _xmlData.@imgheight;
        _textContainer.width = _imgWidth;

        _slideTimer = new Timer(_slideDelay);
        _slideTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, swapSlide);

        _slideContainer1 = new Sprite();
        _slideContainer2 = new Sprite();
        _mainContainer.addChild(_slideContainer1);          
        _mainContainer.addChild(_slideContainer2);

        _currentContainer = _slideContainer2;

        swapSlide(null);
    }

    private function swapSlide(e:Event = null):void {

        if (_slideTimer.running) {

            _slideTimer.stop();
        }

        //  
        if (_randomize == 1) {

            _currentActiveSlide = randomNum();
            //trace("randno1: " + randomNo);
        } else {

            if (_currentActiveSlide + 1 < _slideCount) {

                _currentActiveSlide++;
            } else {

                _currentActiveSlide = 0;
            }
        }



        if (_currentContainer == _slideContainer2) {

            _currentContainer = _slideContainer1;
        } else {

            _currentContainer = _slideContainer2;
        }

        var startImage:String = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].imageSrc;
        var _imgUrl = _xmlData.@imageurl + startImage;
        _startLoc = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].enterfrom;
        _startXY = setStartXY();

        _mainContainer.swapChildren(_slideContainer2, _slideContainer1);


        _slideLoader = new Loader();
        // add event listener when slide is loaded
        _slideLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fadeSlideIn);
        // load the next slide
        _slideLoader.load(new URLRequest(_imgUrl));         
    }

    private function fadeSlideIn(e:Event):void {

        _slideLoader.width = _imgWidth;
        _slideLoader.height = _imgHeight;
        _slideLoader.x = _startXY[0];
        _slideLoader.y = _startXY[1];
        //trace(_slideLoader.content);

        // add loaded slide from slide loader to the
        // current container
        _currentContainer.addChild(_slideLoader.content);

        Tweener.addTween(_currentContainer, { x:0, y:0, time:2 } );
        //Tweener.addTween(currentContainer, { alpha:1, time:FADE_TIME, onComplete:function() { slideTimer.start(); }} );
        //_loaderSwapImg, { x:0, y:0, time:3 } 

        _textTimer = new Timer(_textDelay);
        _textTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, swapText);
        _textTimer.start();
    }

    private function swapText(e:Event):void {

        _textContainer.x = _startXY[0];
        _textContainer.y = _startXY[1];
        _textTimer.stop();
        applyTextFormats();
        Tweener.addTween(_textContainer, { x:150, y:75, time:2, onComplete:function() { _slideTimer.start(); } } )
    }

    private function applyTextFormats():void {

        _textContainer.height = 40;
        _textContainer.text = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].text; 
        _formatsText.bold = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].bold;
        _formatsText.size = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].fontsize;
        _formatsText.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
        _textContainer.setTextFormat(_formatsText);
    }

    private function randomNum():uint {

        var randomNo:uint;

        randomNo = uint(Math.random() * _slideCount);
        return randomNo;
    }

    private function setStartXY():Array {
        //anger startplats för bild, 1 av 5 möjliga

        var xCoordinat:Number;
        var yCoordinat:Number;
        //trace("Enter from: " + _startLoc);

        switch (_startLoc) {

            case "top":
                xCoordinat = 0;
                yCoordinat = -5 - _imgHeight; 
                //trace("image start position: top");
                break;
            case "right":
                xCoordinat = stage.width + 5;
                yCoordinat = 0;
                //trace("image start position: right");
                break;
            case "bottom":
                xCoordinat = 0;
                yCoordinat = stage.height + 5;
                //trace("image start position: bottom");
                break;
            case "left":
                xCoordinat = -5 - _imgWidth;
                yCoordinat = 0;
                //trace("image start position: left");
                break;
            default:
                xCoordinat = 0;
                yCoordinat = 0;
                //trace("image start position: middle");
        }

        var locArray:Array = new Array(xCoordinat, yCoordinat);

        return locArray;
    }       
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The TypeError #1009 means that you're trying to access something inside of an object, but the object itself is null.

When you run this code in the debugger, it should give you the exact line number of the error.  This will allow you to easily see which object is null.  From there, you can work on figuring out why the object is null in the first place and then work to correct that.

Can you paste the exact error message so we can see the stack trace?  It's hard to look through your entire snippet to find the null reference error.

Comment: Sorry for posting all the code but the error msg I got seemed completly unintelligent to me. Shows me for calling the program unintelligent!

Seems I left out a couple of " = new objecttype".
Helped a lot.
Now if just the rest will start to work as it should as well  ;)
Halfway there at least!